# variadic aliases in .gdbinit?

Tags: iphone, xcode, gdb, alias, variadic

Is this possible?

To make a concrete example, consider the following macro:

```
define pos
po ([self $arg0])
end
```

So now if I input pos text, it gets turned into po [self text].  But with multiple arguments, it fails, e.g. pos textLabel text gets turned into po [self textLabel] rather than the desired po [[self textLabel]text].

For another example, just as the three commands

```
po someIvar_
po [self someMethod]
po [[self someMethod]someOtherMethod]
```

print out the descriptions of the three objects referenced, it would be great to define a macro pi that does the same thing for integers, i.e.

```
pi [self someMethod]
```

is the same as calling

```
print (int)[self someMethod],
```

and similarly for

```
pi [[self someMethod]someOtherMethod].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user-defined commands are just a bit more than string-replaces before executing. Your example `pos textLabel text` passes two parameters to a command which only considers one parameter. The second is thrown away. It should result in `po [self textLabel]` before executing. What you do is comparable to the following java-sum-function: 
`int sum(int[] args){return args.get(0);}`

what you need is sth [mentioned here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb.html#Define) :

```
define pos
    if $argc == 1
        po [self $arg0]
    end
    if $argc == 2
        po [[self $arg0] $arg1]
    end
    ..... (as many you need)
end
```

I have not found any kind of a loop. So this should be the only way to do this except it is possible to to pop arg0 out of args and recursive-calls of user-defined-commands are allowed. But I think its easier to complete the example above.

`pi` should be implemented the same way

```
define pi
    if $argc == 1
        print (int)[self $arg0]
    end
    if $argc == 2
        print (int)[[self $arg0] $arg1]
    end
    ....
end
```

maybe there is a better solution but this brings you a step further towards your destination.

Comment: This answer seems to be basically correct, though the pi one is answering a slightly different question from the one I posed.

Comment: ahh, I've just found a useful link which also includes a while-loop and how to access the argv by an dynamic index. This will help you out. I am currently in rush. I hope I will have time today evening (cest).  the link: http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/ns-debugging.html

Comment: no, I have not found a solution for executing a gdb-string. Then I would be able to create the print-string which would then just executed in gdb. but you can play around with the while-loop (the sample-code of the link forgot to write a $ before argc and argv). for getting the whole hierachy you can replace the `==` in my sample-code with `>=`. And thanks for the bounty :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use
po
pi 
command in terminal to see the value of an object or you want to change the value at runtime so here is the solution:

Now here is the best solution to debug and analyze the objective c code in XCode 4. If you want to change the value of a variable at runtime you can change very easily by just Click "Run > Show > Expressions...
and there you can provide value to your variable name.

But I suspect that your problem is not the Objective-C problem, but still I did my best to provide the solution.